# How to use Java regular expression in Oracle regexp_replace

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

How do I use this Java regular expression `("\\d+\\.*\\d+");` in the Oracle `regexp_replace` function. This is working fine in Java, but with Oracle, it is not working.

Example data:

```
<Tier><grade><><sdlc><17,10><> : result should be 17.10
<><sdlc><16,909312> : 16.909312
<><sdlc><11396,87> : 11396.87
<20121217> : 20121217
<UNIT><6086> : 6086
<Tier1><><sdlc><0,47> : 0.47
```

Comment: So, `("ddddabcadd")` is a correct word, or do you mean `("1234asdf1234")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace` then `regexp_substr` followed by `translate` rather than using `regexp_replace`:

```
select translate(regexp_substr(replace(str, ',>', '>')
        , '<[[:digit:]]+(,[[:digit:]]*)?>')
    , ',<>', '.')
from so
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/795b8/6)

From [Oracle Database SQL Language Reference 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#i1239858):

- [TRANSLATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions216.htm#i1501659)
- [REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions153.htm#i78608)
- [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#i1239858)
- [Oracle Regular Expression Support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/ap_posix.htm#g693775)

Comment: Even it is failing incase if string is <><tier><231,> : it should give 234

Comment: any clue how to fix incase <><tier><231,>

Comment: Thanks Shannon,Is it covers all the scenarios along with this :<Tier><grade><><sdlc><17,10><> : result should be 17.10
<><sdlc><16,909312> : 16.909312
<><sdlc><11396,87> : 11396.87
<20121217> : 20121217
<UNIT><6086> : 6086
<Tier1><><sdlc><0,47> : 0.47

Comment: @user1726550: Updated answer to leave out the `<` and `>`, and to match `<123,>` resulting in `123`. Any other cases not covered in your example data?

Comment: <ABC12345> not displaying ABC12345,this case is failing

Comment: So what are you looking for? Give us the rules in English for what you want.

Comment: Specifically extracting `ABC1234` from `<ABC12345>` can be accomplished with `'<[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]]+(,[[:digit:]]*)?>'` But that will extract `Tier1` from `<Tier1><><sdlc><0,47>`? How should we differentiate one rule from the other? And what about `<A1A>`? '<AA123><BC456>` `'<ABC>'` `<14,2><XB12>` ....

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression in Oracle should be `\d+?\.*\d+?`. If you want the period just once, if anything, use `\d+?\.?\d+?` instead. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Oracle/String_Functions/REGEXP_REPLACE_function.htm) you can see more about Oracle regexps.

EDIT: The complete regexp for each line, to just get the number at the end, should be `.*?<\d+?,?\d+?>.*?(\d+?\.?\d+?)` (I'm grouping what you need at the end of the regexp).

EDIT 2: If for some reason the qualifiers `*?` and `+?` don't seem to work, omit the `?` from both. I find it extremely weird that Oracle uses that syntax while other languages use plain `*` and `+`.

Comment: It should work for all the numeric data. It will omit the phrase `result should be`.

Comment: Thanks, so your solution basically will omit all alpha and special characters and keeps only digits?

Comment: Updated, that's the regexp I think you need.

Comment: If my answer got your problem solved, mark it as your answer.

Comment: I don't understand how using the regexp  from edit 1 will be used to transform the `,` to a `.`

Comment: It doesn't. The regexp only catches `(\d+?\.?\d+?)`, the rest is there to be omitted. If he didn't do that the numbers before the actual data would be matched aswell.

Comment: Also he's not trying to replace the commas with periods, he's trying to get the data at the end of the lines.

Comment: OP's example data has a comma in the numbers on the right and a period in the example results on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the Java's regex flavor is not the same as the one used in Oracle's REGEXP_whatever functions.  The Java flavor supports a lot more features, but it's susceptible to badly written regexes that can cause extremely poor performance.  The syntax can be a lot different, too.  In other words, you can't expect a regex to work in Oracle just because it worked in Java.  On the plus side, you don't have to use as many backslashes in Oracle.

I'm not fluent in Oracle, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '([[:digit:]]+),([[:digit:]]+)', '\1.\2', 1, 0, 'c') FROM mytable;
```